# XML PATH SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I have data

```
TIPE| NILAI
PSX     10
GE      10
EG      10
SX      20
SXL     20
SZ      20
```

how to get output like

```
psx/ge/eg = 10
sx/sxl/sz = 20
```

and this is my sytax

```
ISNULL(CAST((SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,TIPE) + ' / '        
FROM tabel
FOR XML PATH('')) AS varchar(max)),'')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @tbl table (TIPE varchar(5), NILAI int);
insert into @tbl values
('PSX', 10),
('GE', 10),
('EG', 10),
('SX', 20),
('SXL', 20),
('SZ', 20);
SELECT DISTINCT  STUFF((SELECT '/ '+TIPE 
        FROM @tbl i WHERE i.NILAI=o.NILAI FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
              + ' = ' + CAST(NILAI AS VARCHAR) AS [RequiredResult] 
FROM @tbl o
```

Result

```
RequiredResult
--------------------
 PSX/ GE/ EG = 10
 SX/ SXL/ SZ = 20
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/WYAJ22189

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @tbl table (TIPE varchar(5), NILAI int);
insert into @tbl values
('PSX', 10),
('GE', 10),
('EG', 10),
('SX', 20),
('SXL', 20),
('SZ', 20);

select NILAI,
       (select TIPE + '/' from @tbl where t.NILAI = NILAI for xml path('')) [TIPE]
from @tbl t
group by NILAI

--for sql server 2017 or newer
select NILAI, string_agg(TIPE, '/') TIPE
from @tbl
group by NILAI
```

Comment: STRING_AGG is available from SQL Server 2017, plus it should be `string_agg(TIPE , '/')` **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=59cccf36aa6523aa9e19addbad3e2840)**

Comment: @lad2025 I think it should work that way also, but thanks for remarks :)